# The operation is not valid due to the current state of the object using sitecore

Tags: c#, powershell, recursion, sitecore, sitecore7

I run this code on sitecore powershell in order to create new language file in path:

```
Get-ChildItem "master:\Print Studio\Print Studio Projects\Maax Product Catalogs\Prof CAN Catalog T2\Books\P_Book\Documents\Full Catalog FR\Pages\Prof-FSBathtubsSectionSnippet\"  -Recurse -Language "en"   | `
    Add-ItemLanguage -TargetLanguage "fr-CA" -IfExist Append | `
    Format-Table Name, Language, Version -auto
```

when use `-Recurse` I get this error

```
The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or does not appear in the correct order. The reason is probably a conflict between an order "format-list" specified by the user and default formatting.

Of type: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException
Stack trace:
   to System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoStepItems (Object input, errorResults Hashtable, Boolean enumerate)
   to Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.CommandWrapper.Process (Object o)
   to Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.SubPipelineManager.Process (PSObject so)
   to Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutputManagerInner.ProcessRecord ()
   to Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FrontEndCommandBase.ProcessRecord ()
   to System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord ()

Inner Exception: The operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Of type: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack trace:
   to System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError (ErrorRecord ErrorRecord)
```

and when don't use `-Recurse` the code works.

Comment: `@(Get-ChildItem ...|Add-ItemLanguage ... ) |Format-Table`

Comment: I would begin troubleshooting by replacing `Format-Table` with `Get-Member`. In this way you can confirm what objects are passed down the pipeline to the output commands. You may also wish to output all the fields and make sure you don't have any duplicate field names.

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot reproduce it here with just this one command **the error** looks like one I was getting as a consequence of PowerShell formatting subsystem's inability to process multiple object types as a result of single formatting operation. Contrary to what one might think - `Format-table` actually results objects and the `Out-Default` operation that is automatically performed at the output end will get lost.

I wonder if executing of this script doesn't work for you on its own or is it only a problem in context of a larger script?

What I would try first is append `| Out-String | Out-Default` at the end of the pipeline. Actually even `| Out-String` should help.

- [Some further hints](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/)